# Regex & PHP $_POST

Tags: php, regex, post

all.  I have a problem retrieving certain POST values incoming to a script I have set up. The POST keys are not changeable as they come from a request from PayPal. However I need some way to get these values dynamically.

When a person purchases multiple items, I get POST values returned such as:

```
item_name=foo
item_name1=bar
item_name2=blah
```

I was thinking that I'll have to do some sort of Regular Expression to get the values, but I'm not sure about the syntax, or if it's even possible to use RegEx on a superglobal.

maybe something like:

```
$exp = "/item_name(d+)/";
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    preg_match($exp,$key,$match);
}
```

As you can tell, I'm really bad with RegEx's. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

--EDIT--

Okay, there's two main POST keys that I need to catch. The problem is there may be any number (positive integer) after the key name:

```
item_name
item_name1
item_name2

item_number
item_number1
item_number2
```

But the ending digit can go all the way to 10, depending upon the number of products purchased.
What I need to do is grab the values for each one of these, and add each item_number to a string to be inserted into a transaction table in my database.
Perhaps something closer to:

```
$itms = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    if (strpos($key, 'item_name') === 0)
    {
        if($itms = '')
        {
            $itms = $val;
        }
        else
        {
            $itms .= ','.$val;
        }
    }

    // don't really want to do it like this because i'd have to do it 10 times
    if (strpos($key, 'item_name1') === 0)
    {
        if($itms = '')
        {
            $itms = $val;
        }
        else
        {
            $itms .= ','.$val;
        }
    }
}
// insert into DB after collecting all values
```

And yes, this is from an IPN.

--EDIT 2 --
This is what I have for my IPN listener script:

```
     case 'ipnHandle' :
        $header = '';
        $retArray = array();
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }

        // post back to PayPal system to validate
        $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
        $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

        // assign posted variables to local variables
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
        $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
        $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
        $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
        $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
        $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
        $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

        if (!$fp)
        {
            $err_msg = 'Could not open the Paypal site to Verify Transaction';
        }
        else
        {
            fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
            while (!feof($fp))
            {
                $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
                if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0)
                {
                    if($_POST['receiver_email'] == "chaoskreator@gmail.com")
                    {
                        if($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed')
                        {
                            $sql = 'SELECT transaction_id FROM '.SHOP_TRANS_TABLE.' WHERE transaction_pid = '.$_POST['txn_id'];
                            $result = $db->sql_query($sql);
                            $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);
                            if($row != 0 && $row != null)
                            {
                                $id_exp = '/^item_number(\d*)$/';
                                $qty_exp = '/^quantity(\d*)$/';
                                $price_exp = '/^mc_gross(\d*)$/';

                                $items = array();
                                $qtys = array();
                                $prices = array();

                                foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
                                {
                                    $match = Array();
                                    if(preg_match($id_exp, $key, $match))
                                    {
                                        $items[] = $val;
                                    }
                                    if(preg_match($qty_exp, $key, $match))
                                    {
                                        $qtys[] = $val;
                                    }
                                    if(preg_match($price_exp, $key, $match))
                                    {
                                        $prices[] = $val;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    $itmStr = implode(",", $items);
                    $qtyStr = implode(",", $qtys);
                    $priceStr = implode(",", $prices);

                    $data = '';
                    $file = "verifyLog.txt";
                    $fh = fopen($file, "a+");
                    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if($data == '')
                        {
                            $data = '['.$key.']'.$value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $data .= ',['.$key.']'.$value;
                        }
                    }
                    $data .= "\r\n".$itmStr."\r\n".$qtyStr."\r\n".$priceStr;
                    fwrite($fh, $data);
                    fclose($fh);
                }
                else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0)
                {
                    $data = '';
                    $file = "failLog.txt";
                    $fh = fopen($file, "a+");
                    foreach($_POST as $value)
                    {
                        if($data == '')
                        {
                            $data = '['.$key.']'.$value;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $data .= ',['.$key.']'.$value;
                        }
                    }
                    fwrite($fh, $data);
                    fclose($fh);
                }
            }
            fclose ($fp);
        }
    break;
```

And this is the response ans logged to verifyLog.txt, with no comma-delimited string appended to the end...:

```
[test_ipn]1,[payment_type]instant,[payment_date]20:47:04 Apr 19, 2011 PDT,[payment_status]Completed,[payer_status]verified,[first_name]John,[last_name]Smith,[payer_email]buyer@paypalsandbox.com,[payer_id]TESTBUYERID01,[business]seller@paypalsandbox.com,[receiver_email]seller@paypalsandbox.com,[receiver_id]TESTSELLERID1,[residence_country]US,[item_name]something,[item_number]AK-1234,[item_name1]somethingElse,[item_number1]1234346dfg,[quantity]1,[quantity1]1,[shipping]8.50,[tax]2.02,[mc_currency]USD,[mc_fee]0.44,[mc_gross]15.34,[mc_gross_1]12.34,[mc_handling]2.06,[mc_handling1]1.67,[mc_shipping]3.02,[mc_shipping1]1.02,[txn_type]cart,[txn_id]4420347,[notify_version]2.4,[custom]xyz123,[invoice]abc1234,[charset]windows-1252,[verify_sign]XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

This is drinving me nuts. lol

Comment: Discover arrays for yourself. Btw, it should be `\d`, not `d`. And `*`, not `+`

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: You need to learn what an array is, and what foreach does. Your code edits are getting further from an answer, while perfectly valid answers have been posted..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just matching a prefix, then regular expressions are arguably overkill. A simple string comparison such as the following would allow you to identify the *items*

```
if (strpos($key, 'item_name') === 0) {
  // $key starts with item_name....
}
```

Comment: That makes much more sense, but how would I handle each one of the instances? Would i have to do `if(strpos($key, 'item_name') === 0){  if(strpos($key, 'item_name1') === 0) {  //do this if you have a second product  }  }`

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but you don't have to. Since you are looking over the whole `$_POST` array, `$key` and `$value` have everything you need. Nothing to hardcode. Do what you need to do for each item inside the logic I posted.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally hit enter while posting earlier. Let me go back and edit the Original Post to show more detail.

Comment: i'm guessing that this is from IPN, you just have to do a foreach()  ***foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)***

Answer (score 1):

The below code will check each one to see if it is one of the item keys, and grab the ID if so. Your example showed one that did not have the digits on it, and since I am not familiar with the Paypal stuff you're dealing with, I went ahead and set the ID to 0 when such a match is made.

```
<?php    
$exp = '/^item_name(\d*)$/';
$values = Array();
foreach( $_POST as $key => $val )
{
    $match = Array();
    //If this is one of the item name variables
    if( preg_match( $exp, $key, $match ) )
    {
        //then put it into the array of captured values
        $values[] = $val;
    }
}

$commaSeparatedForDb = implode( ',', $values );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do originally. Please see EDIT 2 in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$i = 0;

do {

  $key = 'item_name';
  if ($i > 0) {
    $key .= $i; // append number to key if > 0
  }

  if (isset($_POST[$key])) {
    echo "found  $key => ".$_POST[$key];
    // do something with it
  }

  $i++;
} while (isset($_POST[$key]));
```

BASED ON EDITED QUESTION ABOVE

```
if($_POST['payment_status'] == 'Completed')
{
    $sql = 'SELECT transaction_id FROM '.SHOP_TRANS_TABLE.' WHERE transaction_pid = '.$_POST['txn_id'];
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

    // where is sql error checking, what if this sql has failed??

    $row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result);

    if($row != 0 && $row != null) {
        // have you checked to see if the code is ever reaching this point?
        // is it possible your database row doesn't exist

        // this part here looks fine for extracting $_POST values
        $id_exp = '/^item_number(\d*)$/';
        $qty_exp = '/^quantity(\d*)$/';
        $price_exp = '/^mc_gross(\d*)$/';

        // maybe we should declare these arrays earlier. 
        // if this test fails, "if($row != 0 && $row != null) " 
        // you are still imploding the arrays below even though they haven't been declared
        $items = array();
        $qtys = array();
        $prices = array();

        foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {

            // no need to store the matches as you aren't using them anyway                            
            // $match = Array();

            // changed 3x if statements to elseif
            // this is not essential and won't effect the outcomes
            // but is good practice as there is no point testing all 3 cases if first/second case already matches       

            if(preg_match($id_exp, $key)) {
                $items[] = $val;

            } elseif(preg_match($qty_exp, $key)) {
                $qtys[] = $val;

            } elseif (preg_match($price_exp, $key)) {
                $prices[] = $val;
            }
        }
    }

    $itmStr = implode(",", $items);
    $qtyStr = implode(",", $qtys);
    $priceStr = implode(",", $prices);
```

Comment: I actually tried something like this once before and failed miserably. Perhaps I can adapt this to my needs. I'll give it a try.

Comment: there was a typo in this line sorry, echo "found  $key => ".$_POST[$key]; replace $_POST['key'] with $_POST[$key] the rest of the code should work though

Comment: @jason i have added some comments to your revised code and added to my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// find all the matching field names
$fields_to_do = preg_grep('/^item_name\d*$/', $_POST);

// loop over them
foreach($files_to_do as $field) {
    // extract what # they have
    $id = substr($field, 9); // either blank, or 1,2,3,4,etc...

    $name = $_POST["item_name$id"];
    $number = $_POST["item_number$id"];

    ... do stuff ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `$id = substr($field, 8);` actually be `$id = substr($field, 9);` because it should start after the 2nd 'e', the 9th character in the string?

Comment: Hmmmm... No luck with this either. Looks like I'm doomed. :(